# C++ Enum Returning Function to be Used in Constructor

Tags: c++, function, object, constructor, enums

I want to return an enum value from function, as my constructor requires an enum value to be created.

My class :

```
class myBasket{
enum myType {type1, type2, type3} MT;
public:
myBasket(myType thetype) : MT(thetype){} 
};
```

Part in the below is the function that i want to create, but i don't know how to return an enum value so i'm just writing it to show you what i want as it is my problem, also how can i identify that in a header file if needed ?

```
int bSize(int size){
return size;
}
```

The Calling :

```
new myBasket(bSize(chosen_size));
```

Comment: You should declare `myType` in the `public` section if you want things outside the class to be able to use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c++98(also work on c++11)

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass
{
public:
    enum myBasket{one, two, three};

    myBasket bSize(myBasket size){
        return size;
    }

};

int main()
{
    myClass A;
```

//the name of enum do not consider as scope in c++98
        std::cout<

```
    return 0;
}
```

c++11

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass
{
public:
    enum myBasket{one, two, three};

    myBasket bSize(myBasket size){
        return size;
    }

};

int main()
{
    myClass A;
    //only worked on c++11, the enum name work as a scope
    std::cout<<A.bSize(myClass::myClass::one)<<std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

you could state the type of enum in c++11 and do forward declaration too

.hpp

```
enum class myBasket;

class myClass
{
public:


    myBasket bSize(myBasket size);

};
```

.cpp

```
enum class myBasket : int{one, two, three};
```

Beware the enum class can't convert to int implicitly

Answer (score 0):

When you make an enumeration in a class, the class name acts like a namespace.

```
class MyClass
{
  enum SomeType
  {
    Val
  };
};

MyClass::SomeType v = MyClass::Val;
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this is new behavior in C++11.  It also doesn't directly answer the question.

Comment: @jamesdlin Honestly I can hardly tell what he's asking. I had to guess :P

Answer (score -1):

```
enum myType {type1, type2, type3} MT;    
class myBasket{

public:
myBasket(myType thetype) : MT(thetype){} 
}; 

myType bSize(int size){
return somesize; //cant return the input value so modified
}

new myBasket(bSize(chosen_size));
```

Comment: There's no need for `new` here.